# Adding a node to double list

Tags: c, list, double

I want to add a Newnode to the end of a  list but it crashes and goes into a endless loop.
I am attaching the function:
hope to your help!!

```
    void AddProduct(products **head,products *newProduct)
{
    products* current=*head;
    if(current == NULL)
     {
        (*head) =(products *)malloc(1*sizeof(products));
        (*head) = newProduct;
         current=*head;
        return;
     }
    while(current->nextProduct!=NULL)
    {
        current=current->nextProduct;
    }
    //Attaching the new product to the list
    current->nextProduct=newProduct;
    newProduct->prevous=current;
    //SortList(head);
    }
```

Comment: `(*head) = newProduct;` - tell me in your own words what this does

Comment: That malloc() is totally unnecessary, as you're overwriting that pointer anyway. Please also show the code that you're using to initialize and populate the list (i.e. the code that calls this function).

Comment: Well, you could maybe try debugging it?

Comment: [In C you should not cast the return of `malloc`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new element,  you're both accepting it as an argument, *and* allocating it yourself inside the function. You're overwriting the newly allocated pointer with the one passed in, it doesn't make any sense.

Also, you're not setting the `nextProduct` field of the new element.

Finally, you're using too many casts and parentheses.